# How can I replace a link for another using preg_replace?

Tags: php

I was trying something like removing "remove/" from the link

```
   preg_replace("https://mywebsite.com/remove/","https://mywebsite.com/")
```

Comment: do you want to replace everything after domain name? or want replace one url with another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

`str_replace($search, $replace, $subject)`

- `$search` is the needle
- `$replace` is the replacement
- `$subject` is the string we want to modify

So in your case it would be:

`str_replace('remove/', '', 'https://mywebsite.com/remove/');`

Answer (score 1):

Using `str_replace()`,

```
print(str_replace("/remove/", "", $link));
```

Comment: A friendly reminder: When providing a code snippet, you may want to use the built in formatting (either 4 spaces or denoted with backticks (`code`) ). Also, explaining *what* your code does or *why* it works is infinitely more useful than just pasting a simple snippet, as is linking to the relevant documentation for any functions you're using. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Use [str_replace](http://us.php.net/str_replace) for replacing specific parts from your String.

```
echo str_replace("remove/", "", "https://mywebsite.com/remove/");
```

Answer (score 0):

While @common-senses's answer will absolutely work - I'd like to propose another solution. If your link to `https://mywebsite.com/remove/` has already been indexed, you may want to use a [301 Redirect](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection) to your home page and/or issue a [410 "Gone"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) response on the removed page.

If you're going to have a lot of resources that are moved/missing, you may want to use a plugin like [Simple 301 Redirects](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/). Otherwise, you can simply add an `.htaccess` rule like

```
Redirect 301 /remove https://mywebsite.com/
```

Or add it via PHP if you're more comfortable with that

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: " . site_url() ); 
exit();
```